# React Redux async action testing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have my test written to test async actions. I'm currently getting the following error `TypeError: Cannot read poperty 'then' of undefined` and it is pointing to the following line in my code

```
return store.dispatch(actions.fetchMovies()).then(() => {
```

Here is my code :

async actions test :

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import initialState from '../reducers/initialState';
import rootReducer from '../reducers/index';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import * as actions from './actions';
import * as ActionTypes from '../constants/constants';
import nock from 'nock';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import API_KEY from '../config/config';

const MOVIES_API = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key='+API_KEY;

describe('async actions', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    nock.cleanAll();
  });

  it('creates FETCH_MOVIES_SUCCESS when fetching movies is complete', () => {
    nock(MOVIES_API)
      .get()
      .reply(200, {data: {results: [{title: 'Batman vs Superman'}]}});

    const expectedActions = [
      { type: ActionTypes.FETCH_MOVIES },
      { type: ActionTypes.FETCH_MOVIES_SUCCESS, data: {results: [{title: 'Batman vs Superman'}]}}
    ];

    const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, applyMiddleware(thunk));

    return store.dispatch(actions.fetchMovies()).then(() => {
        expect(store.getActions()).to.deep.equal(expectedActions);
      });
  });
});
```

actions:

```
import axios from 'axios';

import * as constants from '../constants/constants';
import API_KEY from '../config/config';


export const fetchMovies = () => {
  const MOVIES_API = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key='+ API_KEY;

  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({
      type: constants.FETCH_MOVIES
    });
    axios.get(MOVIES_API).then(function(response) {
      dispatch({
        type: constants.FETCH_MOVIES_SUCCESS,
        data: response.data.results
      });
    })
    .catch(function(res) {
      dispatch({
        type: constants.FETCH_MOVIES_ERROR,
        msg: res.message
      });
    });
  };
};
```

This is the first time testing async actions so I'm not sure what's going wrong.

Comment: Just want to mention redux-saga http://yelouafi.github.io/redux-saga/ as a way to handle your async action flow. Part of its benefit is the ease in which you can test each part of an async action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [redux-mock-store](https://github.com/arnaudbenard/redux-mock-store) instead of `redux` createStore(). This is a mock store for testing async action creators and middleware. The Github page also includes some examples how to use it.

EDIT:

What happens when you modify your action creator so that it returns the result of `axios.get(MOVIES_API)`?

Comment: I tried using redux-mock-store first, and had the same thing happening. That's why I switched to just creating a normal store because I also saw that in an example. And I shouldn't have to change what the action returns to make this work.....the actions are working fine

Comment: I think you should give it a try. You cannot chain another `then()` when your action creator doesn't return the promise.

Comment: rewrote it and the test is running, now getting an error `Error: Nock: No match for request get https://api.themoviedb....`

Comment: @erichardson30 How did you solve the problem? mind to share :)

Answer (score 2):

It's because your action doesn't return a promise - change your action to return a promise that can be awaited. This isn't required, but if you want to know when your API call has completed (i.e. your unit test wants to know in this particular case), then you can return a promise as a convenience side effect of the action:

```
export const fetchMovies = () => {
  const MOVIES_API = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key='+ API_KEY;

  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({
      type: constants.FETCH_MOVIES
    });

    // Return a promise
    return axios.get(MOVIES_API).then(function(response) {
      dispatch({
        type: constants.FETCH_MOVIES_SUCCESS,
        data: response.data.results
      });
    })
    .catch(function(res) {
      dispatch({
        type: constants.FETCH_MOVIES_ERROR,
        msg: res.message
      });
    });
  };
}
```

;