# Unit testing Redux async actions

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, redux, redux-thunk, nock

I am trying to add unit test cases to my redux actions.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888535/unit-testing-redux-async-function), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39101637/cant-test-redux-async-action) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38355847/react-redux-async-action-testing)

I am using `thunk`, `promise-middleware` in my actions

one of my action is like this

```
export function deleteCommand(id) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'DELETE_COMMAND',
      payload: axios.post(`${Config.apiUrl}delete`, { _id: id })
    })
  }
}
```

unit test for this is

```
import configureMockStore from "redux-mock-store"
const middlewares = [thunk, promiseMiddleware()];
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares)

  it('creates DELETE_COMMAND_FULFILLED after deleting entry', (done) => {

    nock('http://localhost:8081/')
      .post('/delete',{
        _id: 1
      })
      .reply(200, {})

    const expectedActions = [{
      type: 'DELETE_COMMAND_FULFILLED',
      payload: {}
    }]

    const store = mockStore({
      command: {
        commands: []
      }
    })

    store.dispatch(actions.deleteCommand({_id: 1}).then(function () {
      expect(store.getActions())
        .toEqual(expectedActions)
      done();
    })

  })
```

I am using `nock`,`redux-mock-store` configured with `thunk`, `promise middleware`

It gives `then of undefined`

then I changed the action to return the promise, then I got `unhandled promise reject` exception, I added a catch to the action dispatch call.
Now I am getting `Network Error` because nock is not mocking the call.
Also tried `moxios`, changed `axios` to `isomorphic-fetch`, `whatwg-fetch`. Doesn't seem to be working

Where am I doing it wrong?.

Comment: Are you configuring your mock store correctly? i.e. adding the thunk 
 and promise middleware.

Comment: I have updated my question with mock store as well

Answer (score 0):

I know It's from 2017,
But maybe someone will have the same issue.

So the problem is that the arrow function inside `deleteCommand`
 returns undefined.
That's why you get

> It gives then of undefined

**TLDR:**
if you using redux-thunk with redux-promise-middleware
You must return the inner dispatch

[here is the official redux-promise-middleware docs](https://pburtchaell.gitbook.io/redux-promise-middleware/guides/chaining-actions)

The solution is very simple :
**Option 1.**
Add **return** inside the arrow function

```js
    export function deleteCommand(id) {
      return (dispatch) => {
        return dispatch({
          type: 'DELETE_COMMAND',
          payload: axios.post(`${Config.apiUrl}delete`, { _id: id })
        })
      }
    }
```

**Option 2.**
**Remove** the curly braces from the arrow function

```
export function deleteCommand(id) {
  return (dispatch) => 
    dispatch({
      type: 'DELETE_COMMAND',
      payload: axios.post(`${Config.apiUrl}delete`, { _id: id })
    })
}
```

Now you can do

```
store.deleteCommand(<some id>).then(...)
```

In general arrow functions and return

- Return a plain object

```
// option 1
const arrowFuncOne = () => {
  return {...someProps}
}

// option 2
const arrowFuncTwo = () => ({
   ...someProps
})

// This means that you returning an expression 
//same as

// return a result of other function
const arrowFuncCallFunOne = () => callSomeOtherFunc()
// or
const arrowCallFunkTwo = () => {return callSomeOtherFunc()}


// However
// wrong 
const arrowCallFunkNoReturn = () => {callSomeOtherFunc()}
// in this case the curly braces are just the body of the function  
// and inside this body there is no return at all
```